# Write Xamarin version information in Console or file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

Currently, to get Xamarin version information we need to do the following:
Xamarin Studio
Xamarin Studio > About Xamarin Studio > Show Details > Copy Information [button]

I need to have these information in a file or writing them in a console. Do we have a command to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get Visual Studio for Mac version:

```sh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :CFBundleVersion' /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

To get currently used Mono version:

```sh
mono --version
```

or you can look at what current version links to with:

```sh
la /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
```

Similar for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android frameworks:

```sh
la /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current
la /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current
```

**EDIT:** If you only want the version from the `la` commands you can postfix the commands with `| sed 's/^.*-> //g'`. This will replace everything before the `->` including that arrow with nothing, so it will only display the version number. So something like:

```sh
la /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current | sed 's/^.*-> //g'
```

Would give `11.4.0.93`.

For the Mono.framework one, it is an absolute path, so you can pipe again to `sed 's!.*/!!'` to just get the "filename":

```sh
la /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current | sed 's/^.*-> //g' | sed 's!.*/!!'
```

**EDIT:**

Add all this to a script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mono_version=$(ls -n /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current | sed 's/^.*-> //g' | sed 's!.*/!!')
vs_version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :CFBundleVersion' /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist)
ios_version=$(ls -n /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current | sed 's/^.*-> //g')
android_version=$(ls -n /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current | sed 's/^.*-> //g')
echo "mono:" $mono_version
echo "vs version:" $vs_version
echo "ios version:" $ios_version
echo "android version:" $android_version
```

Remember to run `chmod +x` on the `.sh` file. Then you can run this with `sh version.sh` and it will spit out:

```sh
mono: 5.4.1
vs version: 7.3.0.708
ios version: 11.4.0.93
android version: 8.1.0-21
```

Comment: You can just use the following to avoid extracting versions from `ls`/`la` output: 

`MonoVer=$(< /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/VERSION);`

`echo "Mono:                     $MonoVer";`


`XamarinAndroidVer=$(< /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/version);`

`echo "Xamarin.Android:  $XamarinAndroidVer";`


`XamariniOSVer=$(< /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/Version);`

`echo "Xamarin.iOS:              $XamariniOSVer";`