# Visual Studio for Mac - find out components versions in Terminal

Tags: xamarin, terminal, visual-studio-mac

There is a cool GUI solution, like **About Visual Studio > Show Details**.

But is there any chance I can get the same output from CLI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, finally I asked the question on relevant MS site and received an answer that there is no such thing.

Meanwhile, I was able to find two similar questions and answers here on SO (which I missed earlier, likely due to different query phrasing, even though I tried many times).

Here they are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54393403/2518705
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47096260/2518705

Also note my comments to both of them.

Comment: Yeah , there is no such thing about Visual Studio. However Visual Studio For Code can do something in Terminal . I think VS aslo provide a Graphical interface tool to do , so there is no necessary to support CLI .

Answer (score 0):

Terminal window is not a part of the built-in tools within Visual Studio for Mac. There might be some add-ins or extension for this, but I am not aware.

Here is an VS fro Mac [add-in](https://github.com/yuv4ik/vsmacdeepclean) that allows you to open a terminal window and you can do something with CLI.

In addition , *[Team Foundation Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019)* will use GUI Git tool , you can have a look at it .